# Are identify questions allowed though knowing answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, identify

If a OP knows movie or TV show, but OP wants to check that community can identify it or not by giving hints. Are identify-this movie or TV show questions allowed though knowing answer? If Yes, what etiquette should be followed while asking this question?

Can these questions be self answerable( answered by OP )? If yes, how much time you should wait to answer question. ( Let community do some research. ) Or there should be no any limit.

According to me,
**"Answer your own question"** at time of posting question is strictly **not allowed for identify questions**. And if everyone was eager to now answer of identify movie question and you know movie after some days. Then it's OK, to answer by yourself after some days lets say (1-7). No. of days should not be logical.. OP should think on it.

I want to know what moderators and community think of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while answering your own questions is absolutely no problem if you find the answer yourself, directly posting question-answer pairs you already know, just for the sake of its own (or maybe rep), is at least frowned upon, even if being allowed.

But in the case of identify questions, which are already a hot topic and merely allowed for the fact of being useful at least for the OP, it wouldn't be that good an idea to clutter it with more identify questions that don't even help the OP. This is a feedback-driven Q&A site for people to help people, not a quiz game.

So no, if you already know the answer, don't just post the question to play games with the other users (or at least do in a way that nobody realizes this abuse ;)).

Comment: Yes... It's like people will be playing quiz... "Answer your own question" at time of posting question is strictly not allowed for identify questions. And if everyone was eager to now answer of identify movie question and you know movie after some days. Then it's OK, to answer by yourself after some days lets say (1-7). No. of days should not be logical.. OP should think on it.

Comment: Actually, answering your own question in general is a good thing.  While not the best for this site compared to other SE sites, it can provide decent content. I cite [my own self-answered question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/what-is-scott-pilgrims-motivation-for-fighting-gideon-the-second-time/) as an example.

Comment: @TylerShads *"Actually, answering your own question in general is a good thing."* - Of course it is. But in the case of identify questions I cannot see any real value those would contribute to the site other than the very short lived and localized "fun" of a quiz game.

Comment: @ChristianRau It was meant more in the sense of someone who figures out their title after posting the question, which does happen.  We have had a few users in the past that just did the *quiz-game* thing and got downvoted into oblivion.  The community seems smart enough to notice the difference :D

Answer (score 5):

Any question is self-answerable.

If you find the answer yourself, you are encouraged to post it as your answer to your own question so that others can share in this knowledge.

As far as time, if you happen to find the answer after you post it, go ahead and post it as the answer.

If you know the answer already, its encouraged that you do a "BlogOverflow", using the checkbox towards the bottom of the question box to "Answer your own question" that way the question and answer are posted simultaneously.

Comment: Yes. That much I know. But identify-this movie or TV show questions are like OP don't remember that movie or TV. Hence he is asking by clues to identify as per my knowledge till now. So is it allowed though we are knowing movie or TV to ask identify questions?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I don't think so, given that identify questions are already frowned upon for being of use only to the OP anyway. We don't need a whole bunch of additional *"quiz-questions"* that don't even help the OP. This is not a quiz show, but a constructive Q&A site.

Comment: Tyler are you saying that self answered identify question is allowed even user previously know the answer?

Comment: @ChristianRau: I agree.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Technically yes.  But as Christian says, it would be heavily frowned upon.  I'm also trying to answer this objectively without my views on identify questions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion identify questions not allowed though knowing answer.
Self answering is allowed on SE but their is no significance of self answered identify question.

Comment: I also think the same. Its not a damn quiz community. Identify questions require a lot of time from the users to search for. And if the OP knows it, I don't think the question would prove itself more fruitful. They should be closed as `too-localized`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the question and answer are clearly written up and answered with detail, I don't personally see a problem with doing this.  It should make it easier for others that may have the same issue to solve it.